# c++: how to determine if a variable is a vector element

Tags: c++, vector, methods

I have a method, which i want to execute differently depending on if the passed variable is an element of a vector or not, like for example:

```
void method(int a){
if (/*a is an element of a vector*/) //do one thing
else //do another thing
}
```

and then in main:

```
vector<int> a;
a.pushback(1);
int b = 1;
method(a[0]); // does one thing
method(b); // does the other thing
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

Comment: *Why* do you want to do that? It sound like a *very* bad idea.

Comment: The vector holds values.  There is a `1` in the vector regardless of whether you pass in `a[0]` or `1`.  What is the high-level problem you're really trying to solve?

Comment: This sounds like an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the difference between the operations on a vector element vs a standalone variable? You could declare a second function to take a vector and index `void method(vector& a, size_t index){`.

Comment: @HermannDöppes uh i'm sorry. Now i don't know what i was asking for myself. My brain just shortcircuited

Comment: @Yokubasu It happens. Get well soon. (=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for all cases this is impossible, because it actually *requires your function to look at how it is executed*, and there is no such thing in C++. The hated eval() comes to mind.

But in a certain case, when your vector is a global entity, you could pass your variable by link instead of value. Then, you can check if it fits the space between the start and end of the desired vector. This is how it is done(not tested though, but should work)

```
vector<int> v;
//fill it somewhere somehow


void method(int& a)
{
    int* beg = v.data();
    int* end = beg + v.size();
    int* val = &a;
    if ((val >= beg) && (val < end))
    {
        //it is a part of vector
    }
    else
    {
        //it is not a part of vector
    {
}
```

Problem is that you really shouldn't do it this way... As people in the comments said, it DOES look like an XY problem.

Answer (score -1):

An `int` is an `int`. An `int` does not wear a label around its neck, telling everyone where it came from. When an `int` is passed to a function, there is nothing that specifies where the `int` originates.

You should take this as an opportunity to learn about iterators, and implement an overloaded method that takes either an

```
void method(int);
```

for a parameter, or a

```
void method(std::vector<int>::iterator iter);
```

for a parameter (or, perhaps, a `const_iterator`), and invoke the alternative `method()` by passing it an iterator to the `int` in your vector.

Comment: For all we know this method might solve their problem, or it might lead them to certain doom. I think we should wait for OP to clarify before posting guesses at answers.